# What should be the Winding at Primary and Secondary in Transformer?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, multisim

I am trying to build this circuit and testing it in Multisim. As you can See this circuit Produces between 12V-14VDC with 10A but the transformer used in this, I am not been able to get it's Primary and secondary Windings. I have tried Adjusting it in Multisim and tried formula Np/Ns = Vp/Vs.

Can anyone Please tell me How to Find correct Windings? Or what are the Windings? And Please can anyone Tell me What's the Meaning of 24A at Bridge Rectifier? And that F1~1A & F1~10A.

How to make this type of transformer in Multisim and Achieve that 24A Bridge Rectifier?

[image]

[image]

I have Added Multisim Circuit Diagram That I have Found And Done Some Change. Because Original one was not able to draw More Current. So is this One. I don't where is Problem I want Output of 3A Constant But it is drawing 1.194A Only. Please Help Regarding It.

Comment: You might want to add the tag 'multisim' and delete the tag 'switch-mode-power-supply' to get better answers. To clarify, is this question just about how to make multisim model a transformer (and rectifier and fuse ratings of course)?

Comment: This is a "linear power supply", if you search you find videos like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mj2uoTztDl8  which will explain the basics. Instead of simulating the transformer and Bridge rectifier, we generally replace those with a DC voltage source in the simulator. The transformer + bridge rectifier is so simple , we assume that it will generally just work if they are dimensioned properly, so in your case a transformer which can deliver 10A at 18 V and a bridge rectifier which can handle 24 A. Note that the 3 transistors will get **VERY HOT** and will need a **VERY LARGE** heatsink

Comment: Do note that if you want to build this, it will be **expensive** due to the transformer and large heatsink you will need. If you just need 13.8 V up to 10 A at low cost then consider buying a ready-made power supply module like: https://sanyipower.en.made-in-china.com/product/jCHJWzlOlUcs/China-13-8V-10A-5A-Rechargeable-UPS-Power-Supply-Emergency-Power-Supply.html

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Actually My application is that I need to Supply 5V 3A or 2.5 A DC constant to Raspberry Pi and Need to Supply 5V 1A  DC to Arduino Constant so i am building a PSU to generate 12V 10A DC then I will Make Individual Power Ckt for the respective Devices. If you can Provide any Idea How to make this Possible?

Or say Can If we convert 230V AC to Directly 5V 3A DC and supply it to Raspberry PI and then take this 5V 3A DC and Convert it to 5V 1A DC and Supply it to Arduino. Is this Possible? Can you Suggest me methods to achieve this?

Comment: Power an RPi and an Arduino, why not simply use a USB phone charger (or two)? They're cheap, efficient and easy to use. You really do not need to convert mains AC into 12 V at 10 A and then make another circuit to get 5 V. That is WAAAAAAAY to complex and expensive. Just use some USB power supplies. That will work fine. Unless you have some special need (and I don't think you do) then someone else already made a power supply which will be cheaper and safer than anything you can make at this moment.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ok, RPI and Arduino are Working in UART (Together in One Device and Are Connected). I have Tried Connecting Arduino to RPI Directly via USB but the Voltage and current generated from the 5V pin and GPIO Pin were Not Enough. That's why I am building My Own PowerSupply Just need a Guidance and Right Direction and little help in Between.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Will this be Alright:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2PCS-AC-DC-12V-5A-Switching-Power-Supply-Circuit-Board-DC-Voltage-Regulator-Module-For-Monitor/32796350586.html?spm=a2g01.11638294.list_product.1.274f4788Ow9Sz6&gps-id=5562377&scm=1007.19164.119559.0&scm_id=1007.19164.119559.0&scm-url=1007.19164.119559.0&pvid=d7a977f9-c675-4166-8f24-60dbb404d18f

And if yes can you suggest me Powering Plan from this to RPI and Arduino?

Comment: *but the Voltage and current generated from 5V pin and GPIO Pin were Not Enough. Thats why I am building My Own PowerSupply* You're making this into an XY problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem You want to solve problem X with solution Y but you fail to search for the root cause of problem X. My bet is that your basic UART 5 V problem can easily be solved. If you want to make a supply for educational purposes, fine, then study and do so. But you do not need it. You need to figure out what is going wrong and why, then solve that. Yes that isn't always easy.

Comment: *can you suggest me Powering Plan from this to RPI and Arduino?* Yes use a USB power supply. Connect all GNDs together, Connect all +5V to USB 5 V, done.

Comment: UART is for Communication Between Arduino and RPI. But for the Power Supply arduino has to use RPI's 5v Pin supply or USB. so if it Uses from RPI then The devices Attached to RPI will work Not Efficiently. So I am Providing them Individually Power Supplies.

Comment: I suggest that you find and study some simular projects on internet and see how they do the same thing. You're not the first to try this and the way to make it work is easy.

Comment: USB Power Supply with 3A will be Fine Right? So I have to make it on My on like converting 230V AC to 5V 3 A DC then Provide to both of them.

Comment: Yeah, I will definitely Do More Research. But I have Not Yet Found Somone tried like I am Doing. Nothing on Youtube or Google Searches. i think Now I have to refer All pages of Google Researches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are transformer and complete transformer boards which will output the correct voltage. I strongly discourage the idea to build a transformer by yourself (which your questions for the right number of turns implies). Actually you should not touch main power supply at all if you have not a very good idea what is going on at those voltage levels. In the worst case you or somebody else might get severely hurt!

Furthermore your comment "Can If we convert 230V AC to Directly 5V 3A DC and supply it to Raspberry PI and then take this 5V 3A DC and Convert it to 5V 1A DC and Supply it to Arduino" is an indication of a missconcept regarding voltages and currents:
generelly speaking one has to make sure that a (voltage) supply give the right level of voltage (in your case 5V). Additionally the supply need to be potent enough to provide at least the maximum current required by your devices. Which means as long as the (maximum allowed) current rating of your supply is greater than the drawn current your will be fine. Considering the numbers you gave there any supply abled to supply 5V with a current rating greater than 3+1A should be fine to power your RPI and arduino in parallel.

To your question:
The ratio is for the transformer is actually computed via the formular N1/N2 as you figured it out. But one has to make sure that the number of turns on the primary side is not to low (to avoid heating due to high currents) or to high (low maximum power transfer). A source describing some parameters and formular for such an effort is http://engineerexperiences.com/design-calculations.html . But again: only do it if you know what you are dealing with.

Modern AC/DC converter (like the little power grid to USB thingy) actually use a far more advanced approach. There the AC is first rectified then chopped with a high frequency, transformed via a much small transformer and then rectified again (for details search for Switched-mode power supply). That is the reason why your design will mostlikely have the size of a shoes box while there are adapters out providing multiple usb ports with 5V/5A in size of an arduino.

TL;DR Do not tamper with mains electricity voltages if you do not know what you are up to. Make sure that you got all the basics before trying to solve a problem by throwing more stuff unto it. Try to stick with out-of-the-box solution (if this is an option for you/do not intentionally want to make it harder as it could be).

Comment: Hi, I have added a Circuit That I have Created in Multisim for the test. The Person on who's site was this written that this Provides 5V 2.5A DC But it is Showing only 1.12A. Can you help me With this? 

And Are You Saying that if I supply 5V 3A to both Raspberry PI and Arduino Simultaneously There will be No issue? Like It depends on the load how much it uses as if it uses 1A then it would work. Additional 2 A will not Interfere with it.right?

Comment: Regarding the consumption question: I am not really sure if I get your question correctly but you statement regarding the "It depends on the load how much it uses as if it uses 1A then it would work" is correct. So a 3A supply will be abled to power a device which draws up to 1A. So supplies maximum current is like the amount of cars which can use a street. As long as the number of cars do not exceed the capacity of the street everything is fine. Same for supplies. As long as the load current does not exceed the maximum allowed current everything is fine.

Comment: But keep in mind: currents are additive for parallel circuits. If you supply an arduino and a RPI in parallel you have to make sure that the sum of the max currents drawn by the devices do not exceed the capacity of the connected supply.

Comment: Can you Please Help Me Regarding The Circuit I have Made Above I am getting 1.19A instead of 3A?